# Why I can't take differential backup of primary replica?

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

I am trying to take a differential backup of my primary database by connecting to the primary replica, but I can't do that. We use **SQL Server 2017 EE with latest CU**. Database is in full recovery model and full backups are taken everyday at night. The **Copy-only backup** option and **OK** button are grayed out. Could someone help to understand why it is not possible to perform the mentioned action?

[image]

Comment: it works) I wonder why this does not work using UI. I use latest version of SSMS. I performed the same experiment in my lab environment and there was no any issue. Interesting behavior.

Comment: You are right Sir. Anyway I am going to use T-SQL as you suggested. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Only thing I'll add is try uninstalling and reinstalling SSMS and see if that fixes the issue. Otherwise Aaron's workaround should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's anybody's guess why the UI is preventing you from being able to use the copy-only checkbox. So I can't give you an answer and don't think it would be productive to throw out guesses. I can offer a workaround (and generally, this is a better way to accomplish just about anything a pointy-clicky UI tries to do for you):

- Press the `Script` button
- Copy the script to a new query editor window
- Add the `COPY_ONLY` option manually
- Voila

If you want a definitive answer in addition to a workaround, you'll probably have to talk to Microsoft, who wrote the code, has source code access, can meaningfully debug if they can reproduce your scenario, etc.